# Filling array of Java objects in initialization

Tags: java, arrays, oop, initialization

I have an implemented data structure called `List` (it's a singly linked list). I have the following code in my Java program:

```
List[] Adjacent = new List[N]; // Trying to create an array of N List objects
```

Suppose N = 6. I want `Adjacent` to be an array of six elements where each one of them is a `List` object itself. But when I try to access it, the array is actually an array of N null references. What is going on?

Of course I did the following to solve my problem:

```
for (int p = 0; p < N; p++) 
    Adjacent[p] = new List();
```

But that's not what I really want. Is there a more efficient/nice way to do it?

Comment: I would avoid the class name `List`. It is the name of a widely used interface...

Comment: There is no such thing as a "null object".

Comment: @Ingo corrected it to "pointers"

Comment: @rodrigoalves correct to "references", Java doesn't have pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have

```
List list;
```

this is a *reference*, not an object. To have an object you have to create one with `new List(...)`. There is no way to work around this. You have to initialise your references to actual objects.

Also, it is far worse to be creating a class which does the same thing with a similar name to something already built in. I suggest you use a List of List like this:

```
List<List<String>> listofLists = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) listOfLists.add(new ArrayList<>());
```

It is more efficient for you to reuse existing classes.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. After create new array you should fill it manualy. Of course we have `Arrays.fill(array, object)` method but it will set the same object to all positions in array.

Answer (score 3):

There will be a “nice” way to to it with Java 8:

```
MyObject[] array=Stream.generate(MyObject::new).limit(N).toArray(MyObject[]::new);
```

`Stream.generate(MyObject::new)` will create an unlimited stream of objects provided by a `Supplier` which is the default constructor of `MyObject`in our case, `limit(N)` obviously limits the number of objects and `toArray(MyObject[]::new)` will store the objects into an array constructed by an `IntFunction<A[]>` that constructs an array using a specified `int` which is set to the equivalent of `new MyObject[i]` in our case. The stream will provide the limit `N` for that `i` parameter.

Though the last part is not the real spirit of *streams*. Normally, you would direct the stream to the consumer dealing with the objects and omit the array completely.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose N is **always** 6 ...

```
List[] l = new List[]{new List(),new List(),
       new List(),new List(),new List(),new List()};
```